# Modify parent props in child, then reuse the props in child once modified

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, state

I have a React app where I'm attempting to modify the props that I've passed from my parent component. What I want to do is once I've clicked a counter in my child component, to have the parent props be modified and be able to be reused throughout my two components.

**How can I modify parent props in my child component and then reuse those modified props throughout all child components in my app?**

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setInitState = this.setInitState.bind(this)
    this.state = {value: 0} 
}

  setInitState() {
    this.setState({
      value: 0 // I want to modify and reuse this in my child components
    })
  }

  changeValue(e) {
    console.log('parent change', e)
    let value = e;
    this.setState({value: value});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <CostBox />
            <Input changeValue={this.changeValue} {...this.state} />
            <TotalBox changeValue={this.changeValue} {...this.state} />
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: #2B3636;
`;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Input.js**

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  subtractUnit() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value - 1 // once the button has been clicked, I want to have this modified value be modified in the parent and then reusable throughout this and my other component
    });
  }

  addUnit() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1 // once the button has been clicked, I want to have this modified value be modified in the parent and then reusable throughout this and my other component
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Col md={6}>
    <CenterBox>
    <h5>
      <form>
        <InputLabel># OF UNITS<br />
            <UnitInput type='number' id="total-units" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></UnitInput>
        </InputLabel>
      </form>
      <IconContainer onClick={this.subtractUnit.bind(this)}><MdRemoveCircleOutline style={iconLeft} /></IconContainer>
      <IconContainer onClick={this.addUnit.bind(this)}><MdAddCircleOutline style={iconRight} /></IconContainer>
    </h5>
    </CenterBox>
    </Col>
    )
  }
}
```

**TotalBox.js**

```
class TotalBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value, // once one of the counter buttons is clicked I want to use it in this component to output on the final total label
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col md={3}>
        <RightBox>
          <TotalCostHeader>TOTAL COST</TotalCostHeader>
          <TotalCostLabel>${this.state.value * 175.50}</TotalCostLabel>
        </RightBox>
      </Col> 
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NEVER mutate props, you will probably warned from the linter, if one is active in your project. The flow you are searching for is probably

Parent with method *myMethod* that changes *state.myAttr* -> *myAttr* and *myMethod* passed as props to child -> child calls *props.myMethod* and receives updated prop from the parent